# Average from Array - PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, calculation

```
<?php
$games = [
    ["Call of Duty", "Shooter", 59.95],
    ["Rocket League", "Sport", 19.95],
    ["Assassins Creed", "RP", 49.95]
];

?>
```

// i have an assignment where they want me to get the average string length from the titles and a average game price and echo it out like :

```
// echo "average price: €" . $averageprice;
// echo "average length of titles: " . $averagetitle
```

it needs to include:

- number_format
- for loop

i have tried numerous options but only got into coding for half a year now and havent really gotten into php. tried looking up different functions to use but couldnt get my head wrapped around it so i wonderd if the amazing coding community could heklp me out.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, your best attempt (code) - what exactly does not work as expected? With a bit of research this assignment does not look like an insurmountable problem, even for a beginner, IMHO. Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Average is computed as `$sum_of_values/$number_of_values`, so you can use for loop to loop throught all the items and sum them up as for example `$sum_of_prices += $current_item[2]` and finally divide it by length of array (`count($games)`).

For length of string, just find out length of string by `strlen($current_item[0])` and add it to sum of lengths of titles like in prices. Finally divide it by length of array. You can use same loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to have understand right your request,
If games informations are always in the same position you can try something like this:

```
    <?php
$games = [
    ["Call of Duty", "Shooter", 59.95],
    ["Rocket League", "Sport", 19.95],
    ["Assassins Creed", "RP", 49.95]
];

$avg_name_lenght = 0;
$avg_game_price = 0;

foreach($games as $game ){
    $game_name_lenght = strlen($game[0]);
    $avg_name_lenght += $game_name_lenght;
    $game_price = $game[2];
    $avg_game_price +=$game_price;
}

$avg_name_lenght = $avg_name_lenght / count($games);
$avg_game_price = $avg_game_price / count($games);

echo "<p>average price: €" . $avg_game_price."</p>";
echo "<p>average length of titles: " . $avg_name_lenght."</p>";

?>
```

Comment: Otherwise if elements in array are in  different positions you can to use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
It includes a for loop en the number_format function:

```
function getAveragePrice($array) {
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $sum += $array[$i][2];
    }

    return number_format($sum / count($array), 2);
}

function getAverageLength($array) {
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $sum += strlen($array[$i][0]);
    }

    return number_format($sum / count($array), 2);
}

$averageprice = getAveragePrice($games);
$averagetitle = getAverageLength($games);

echo "average price: €" . $averageprice . "<br>";
echo "average length of titles: " . $averagetitle . "<br>";
```